# How to ignore special characters in string sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, utf-8

Is it possible in Javascript to sort an array of strings by ignoring special characters in the array items? For example, if I have the following array:

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "@Orange", "Apple", "$Mango","apricot"];
```

and I use `fruits.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))`, to sort the array, I receive the following result:

```
["$Mango","@Orange","Apple","apricot","Banana"]
```

But what I want is `["Apple","apricot","Banana","$Mango","@Orange"]`

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the characters from the strings before you compare them.

```
const specialChars = /a regular expression that expresses your definition of "special"/g;
fruits.sort(
    (a,b) => 
        a.replace(specialChars, "")
         .localeCompare(
             b.replace(specialChars, "")
         )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The process would be simple - Just remove special char and then compare.

```
var fruits =  [".Banana", "@Orange", "Apple", "$Mango","apricot"];

fruits.sort(function (a, b) {
  function getRaw(s) {
    return s.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%!.„'":*‚^_¤?<>|@ª{«»§}©®™ ]/g,'').trim();  
   }
    return getRaw(a).localeCompare(getRaw(b));
  });

 console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Just FYI: that formatting is very misleading, and it looks like this code in incorrectly nested…

Comment: but when you run it , this gives the required result

Comment: Yes, but at first glance it looks like the call to `getRaw(a)` is within the definition of `function getRaw` itself…!

Comment: Pro tip: formatting (indenting) is *extremely important* to reduce bugs and improve maintainability.   You could put your code all on one line and it would still "give the required result".

Comment: I guess you miss the curly braces after. trim() in reading the code

Comment: yes, thank you I will take care of the formatting

Comment: Thanks for the solution @SahilVerma but I was actually looking for some out-of-the-box solution provided by Javascript through some encoding, etc. since it is being done automatically on the server side by the Postgresql and I have to match that behavior.